# Keep getting "Page not found". What to do?

Tags: python, css, django

**Can someone please help me solve this problem I just started learning Django.

I keep getting getting "PAGE NOT FOUND " whenever i open/click the list/entries

In my "entries" folder i have

Css.md

Django.md

Git.md

Python.md

HTML.md**

[screenshot of   "Page not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrrXt.png)

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry, name="entry"
```

**views.py**

```
from django import forms

class NewEntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)


def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
        })

def entry(request, entry):
    entries = util.get_entry(entry)
    if entries is None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "message1": "Sorry",
            "message2": "your requested page was not found "
        })
  
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "content": entries,
        "form": NewEntryForm
    })
```

**index.html**

```
    {% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}
    {% block title %}
        Encyclopedia - {{title}}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block body %}
        <h1>All Pages</h1>
        <ul>
            {% for entry in entries %}
                <li><a href="{{entries}}"></a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

**entry.html**

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia - {{title}}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% if not content%}
            <div>Sorry, your requested page was not found </div>
        {% else %}
            {{ content | safe }}

                <div><a href="{% url 'edit' entry %}">Edit this entry</a></div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show your complete index function in your views.py

Comment: have you read the polls app tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/  ?

Comment: Okay thank you i'll try to read to read the tutorial again if there is something i miss

Answer (score 0):

edit anchor tag in entry.html. URL is given wrong, Do this

```
<div><a href="{% url 'entry' entry %}>Edit this entry</a></div>
```

instead of

```
<div><a href="{% url 'edit' entry %}>Edit this entry</a></div>
```

Comment: I  have  edited it but still the result is still the

Comment: i added a screenshot of the page above

Answer (score 0):

you forget to close "".

write this:

```
<div><a href="{% url 'edit' entry %}">Edit this entry</a></div>
```

simple.....

Comment: I already have the "  i guess i have deleted when i copy the code but still the result is still the same